# How to import JS file as a module?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on three projects(server, tv client and mobile client). They communicate through a web socket using message types. It's essential that message types should be consistent across the three projects. I've already setup git to manage the three projects within 1 root folder.

```
projectA // server project
projectB // tv client project
projectC // mobile react client project
shared-files <--- this is where i'd like to place any shared files ( in this case my message type constants )
```

At the moment i am stuck with importing outside assets to my react project.
I have tried by simply specifying the path to the file but react complains about importing assets outside src.
I also realized that when i do deploy my react app, the file wont be bundled so this wont work. My next idea was something along the lines of including the .js file as project dependencies thru an install but I have no clue how to do that.  Have you done something like this yourself? any suggestions?

Comment: You can go with monorepo where you can share your code between different project easily.

Comment: Have you tried adding hooks like below ?
`useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "/path/to/resource.js";      <-- this is the path from where this will import, like s3 path
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  }
}, []);`

Comment: @HarshMangalam thank you for your suggestion. I checked out monorepo. It looks exactly like what i need. I will check into it. On the other hand for now what I ended up doing was , i wrote a simple cp script which runs on npm start:dev,   it basically will copy the resource i need into the repo that needs it. this was my cheap solution for "custom project dependencies "